# In C++, how do I use constant variable defined in one file elsewhere?

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm c++ beginner.

```
// a.cpp

int g_x{ 1 };    // that linkage is extern-linkage by default

extern const int g_y{ 2 };  // change the linkage of variable g_y from intern-linkage to extern-linkage
```

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>

extern int g_x;         // forward declaration
extern const int g_y;   // forward declaration 

int main() {
    std::cout << "The value of g_x is " << g_x << '\n';
    std::cout << "The value of g_y is " << g_y << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

The value of g_x: 1
The value of g_y: 492240950

what is "492240950" ?

I want to output g_y when I execute following cli:
`>> g++ main.cpp a.cpp --std=c++14`

What should I improve ?

---

My apologies, answerer!

I have made a mistake source code so I modify it.
In a.cpp: extern const g_y{ 2 } ---> extern const int g_y{ 2 };

I haven't solve above the issue yet.

Although I say again, my desire output is following:

The value of g_x: 1
The value of g_y: 2

I expect that my knowledge relevant to the property of constant variable is lack

---

**The progress of this issue**

I removed `extern` keyword in a.cpp, but I haven't  solve the issue.
Its output is not the value of g_y, still 9 digit consecutive number.

---

**Source**

Link: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/external-linkage/

Since I want to display the value of g_y in console, I have added its output implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the same thing (g++ 7.5.0 on Ubuntu 18.04) and got the correct values of `g_x` and `g_y`. I tried both `-O3` and `-O0` Is it possible that you just compiled different source files (or versions of the source files) than you thought, or ran the wrong compiled executable? Try recompiling and checking the timestamp before you run it.

Comment: int keyword was missing on constant variable definition in a.cpp.

The compile is successful!
thank you

Answer (score 4):

You cannot initialize a variable in the same place as you declare it `extern`.  The entire point of `extern` is to tell the compiler that the symbol is defined elsewhere.

If `a.cpp` is providing these variables, then it should define them like this:

```
int g_x = 1;
const int g_y = 2;
```

When the linker looks for these symbols which are declared `extern` in `main.cpp`, it will then find the ones from the compiled object file for `a.cpp`.

If the variables are defined as non-extern in *another* source file as well, then the linker will give an error telling you there are multiple definitions.

It is common practice for any source file that exposes global variables to provide a header file where these variables are declared extern.  So, for example, you would have a header `a.h` with the `extern` declarations in it, and `main.cpp` would include that.

Comment: In C++ the rules say "A name of file scope that is explicitly declared const, and not explicitly declared extern, has internal linkage, while in C it would have external linkage", so I'm not convinced your change would work. You certainly need to mark `g_y` as `extern` in `a.cpp` for the linkage to be correct. Why not also initialise it at the same time?

Comment: @ArthurTacca no, you don't need it to be `extern` in `a.cpp`. You only need external linkage to refer to a variable in *another* translation unit.

Comment: Sorry answerer!  I had mistake in above question.  I haven't solve my issue yet.

Comment: @Caleth That is not true for `const` variables: unless you explicitly mark them `extern` then it's as if you declared them as `static` (the formal terminology for this is "internal linkage"). That quotation from my last comment is straight out of the C++ standard. If you tried your suggested fix then you would get an undefined symbol error from the linker because `g_y` in `a.cpp` has internal linkage so isn't seen by the linker.

Comment: BTW, the reason for this is so that you can put the *definition* `const int g_y = 2` in the header file and not get multiply-defined symbol error from the linker. This was important back before C++ had the notion of `inline` variables, and you would want to put your constant in the header file so you could use it in compile-time expressions like the size of an array in a local variable declaration. (This is actually a possible fix for tyau 98's problem, but doesn't explain why their getting their problem in the first place.)